# Setting up Fido after username/password login

Tags: react-native, wso2, fido, wso2-identity-server

Using WSO2 server if that makes a difference, but would like to know if this makes sense for other servers that support Fido or webauthn.

What I want is to improve in a react native application that is currently using WSO2 with username/password authentication. I want to change it that the user first enters username or password, but after that can use biometrics to login with their phone instead of typing in that username and password again.

All the examples I saw were that to follow instructions to first register the device. Can I have the first login process be used to register that device for Fido login. Am I researching the correct web standards?

Comment: How are you planning to register the fido device, Via WSO2 portal or APIs?

Comment: APIs, but I don't have good insight on how to do that.  Do not want users to access the portal.